# How to handle SOAP service within persistent Perl web application with cookies?

Tags: web-services, perl, soap, wsdl, dancer

Due to the fall of [SOAP::WSDL](http://p3rl.org/SOAP::WSDL) which had generated me real Perl modules I have to look for something other in order to handle a SOAP service. The generated modules won't work starting from Perl v5.18.

I have the following situation with my web application.

- I have a [PSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSGI) compatible, [Dancer2](http://perldancer.org/) driven, persistent web application.
- The web application handles multiple concurrent customers.
- The web application is between the customer and an external SOAP service.
- The SOAP service uses customer sessions via cookies which have to be integrated on the web application internally for the customer.
- The web application holds an WSDL file copy of the SOAP service.

I'm looking for a module that creates an interface out of the WSDL file and handles parameter/schema validation and communication with the SOAP service. I would like to call a method (SOAP call) with parameters (SOAP call parameters) and receive a cleaned data or object structure of the response.

The problem is that the web application needs to handle multiple concurrent customer cookie sessions. So I need a module which offers the possibility to override the cookie jar for that particular request and extract the cookies after the request without causing interference with other concurrent requests.

I found [XML::Compile](http://p3rl.org/XML::Compile) which I can initialize as a singleton at web application start up. But with this solution I ran into problems with interfering other customer requests. So the requests are not separated. Initializing XML::Compile for every request is not the solution either because it will parse the WSDL and generate handlers over and over again for every request the customer sends to the web application.

Is there any solution/module that fits my needs or do I miss something with XML::Compile and it's possible with it?

Comment: SOAP::WSDL has recent [maintenance releases](https://metacpan.org/release/SOAP-WSDL). It maybe worthwhile contacting the maintainers or submitting an [RT ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=SOAP-WSDL), if you haven't already

Comment: A friend of mine even have spoke with him in person. And with the XML::Compile author. I'm wondering why there is any update on SOAP::WSDL.

Comment: And the documentation still says: "don't use me":
`This module is not recommended for new application development. Please use ... instead if possible. ... This module has a large number of known bugs and is not being actively developed`

Comment: New updates and a new maintainer - a fair bit of effort in fixing this old [perl 5.15.7 bleedperl failure](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=74257), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Catalyst?

I've been happy using [Catalyst::Controller::SOAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Controller::SOAP) and its companion [Catalyst::Model::SOAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Model::SOAP) to build SOAP/WSDL servers and consumers, being able to integrate Perl Applications even with [Microsoft Document Literal-Wrapped](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Controller::SOAP#Support-for-Document-Literal-Wrapped) thing.

Even if not using Catalyst you may probably learn from its code. It uses [XML::Compile::WSDL11](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::WSDL11).